# Integrating Splide.js Auto Scroll Carousel with Next.js 13: How to Properly Set it Up?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13, splidejs

I'm trying to integrate Splide.js, a lightweight and responsive carousel library, into my Next.js 13 project, but I'm encountering some issues with the setup. I've followed the documentation and tried various approaches, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Could someone provide guidance on how to correctly set up and use Splide.js Auto Scroll* within a Next.js 13 application?

I'm working on a personal web application using Next.js 13, and I'd like to incorporate the Splide.js carousel to showcase some images. However, I'm facing difficulties with the integration process. Here's what I've tried so far:

**I installed the Splide.js package using npm:**

```
$ npm install @splidejs/splide
```

**I also imported Splide.js AutoScroll from its extension, like Below:**

```
$ npm install @splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll
```

**I created a React component for the carousel:**

```
const splide = new Splide( '.splide', {
  type   : 'loop',
  drag   : 'free',
  focus  : 'center',
  perPage: 3,
  autoScroll: {
    speed: 1,
  },
} );

splide.mount();
```

However, the carousel is not rendering as expected, and I'm not seeing any errors in the console. Am I missing something in this setup? Are there any specific considerations when using Splide.js with Next.js 13?

Answer (score 0):

```
options={{
        type: `${block.dataType === "Sponsors" ? "loop" : "slide"}`,
        drag: "free",
        focus: "center",
        extensions: { AutoScroll },
        autoScroll: {
          pauseOnHover: true,
          speed: 1,
        },
```

Import AutoScroll and add to `extensions:{AutoScroll}` and this `autoplay: true,` ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I’ve tried that but definitely it failed working out!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const splide = new Splide( '.splide', {
  type   : 'loop',
  drag   : 'free',
  focus  : 'center',
  perPage: 3,
  autoScroll: {
    speed: 1,
  },
} );

splide.mount({ AutoScroll });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For `React` you can simply do the following to add the Autoscroll extension:

```
<Splide
  options={{
    type: "loop",
    focus: "center",
    autoScroll: {
      speed: 1,
    },
    drag: "free",
  }}
  extensions={{ AutoScroll }}
>
...
</Slide>
```